# what does "/" mean in css border-radius property?

Tags: css, border

I was looking for some curved footer and ended encountered [this one](https://codepen.io/louy2/pen/qKYLJM)

then i saw that it use a "/" on the `border-radius` property, what does it mean?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question doesn't show any research effort. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) before asking.

Comment: for a while i forgot the slash is called "slash", sorry for that, will do my best to prevent it happen again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/` is used to separate the values of the horizontal and vertical radii.

Paraphrasing from [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#border-radius): Values before the slash will set the horizontal radius and values after the slash will set the vertical radius. If no radius is given, then both radii will be equal.

To give an idea of how the horizontal and vertical radii work, you can draw a quarter of a circle on the relevant corner (such as the  top-left corner). If you set the `border-radius`to: `border-radius:1000px 0 0 0 /90px 0 0 0;`, the horizontal radius will stretch by 1000px and thus stretch the curve of the top-left corner by 1000px to the right. The vertical radius will stretch by 90px and thus the curve of the top-left corner will stretch 90px downward.

You can check out this [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/setting-css3-border-radius-with-slash-syntax/) for another explaination.